# How do I get the non-maximised window size of a form?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, settings, save

I'm trying to save my the state of a `System::Windows::Forms::Form` when my application shuts down. I can record the window's size, position and window state without any issues but if the window was maximised when it was closed the `::Size` member records the maximised size of the window.

Is there any way to record the non-maximised size or do I need to intercept the on-maximise event and record it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not readily available, you'd have to P/Invoke GetWindowPlacement.  The best approach is to only record the window size if the form is in the proper state.  For example:

```
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            Properties.Settings.Default.WindowSize = this.Size;
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
```

Comment: GetWindowPlacement is great except that it records locations in WorkingArea coordinates, which you can't readily mix with ScreenArea coordinates (if you do, your window will move by the height of the system taskbar)

Comment: Rather than constantly persisting this value on every resize, you can also, on shutdown, check to see if this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Normal and if it's maximized or minimized, use the RestoreBounds property instead.

Comment: It isn't constantly persisted.  Not until the program calls the Save() method.  Best done at program exit.